# obout gridview - using edit template

Tags: asp.net, templates, gridview, obout

Hello guys i am working with obout gridview and i am trying to make an edit template for my grid, i looked up on their site but i still cant solve a problem with updating the needed rows .
When i pick a row to edit i got a template with different look that has 4 textboxes that should be connected to 4 of the cells on the choosen row of the grid. The problem those textboxes aint getting updated  and even when i as a user fill them up and click update  i can see on debugger that they are strings of "".

This is the grid altough maybe there is something else that needs to be done to solve this? i am kinda new to this, Thanks in advance!

```
        <cc1:Grid ID="budgetGrid" runat="server"
        EnableTypeValidation="false" CallbackMode="true" Serialize="true"      AutoPostBackOnSelect="false" 
            AllowGrouping="True" FolderStyle="~/styles/premiere_blue"
          OnUpdateCommand="UpdateRecord" 
            DataSourceID="budgetSql" GroupBy="year,departmentName" ShowColumnsFooter="True" 
            ShowGroupFooter="True" ShowMultiPageGroupsInfo="False" 
        AllowAddingRecords="False" PageSize="-1" AllowPageSizeSelection="False" 
        AllowPaging="False">

                     <GroupingSettings AllowChanges="False" />

            <Columns>

                <cc1:Column ID="Column1" runat="server" AllowEdit="true" HeaderText="Edit" 
                    width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="column0" HeaderText="ID" readonly="true" Visible="false" runat="server" DataField="id"  FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />

                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="Column2" HeaderText="Department" readonly="true" Visible="false" runat="server" DataField="departmentName" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="Column3" HeaderText="Sub Dep" readonly="true" runat="server" DataField="subDepName" Width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller"  />
                </cc1:Column>

                <cc1:Column ID="Column11" HeaderText="Q1Bud" readonly="false" runat="server" DataField="Q1B" Width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                    <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="budgetQ1" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="Column8" HeaderText="Q2Bud" readonly="false" runat="server" DataField="Q2B" Width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                    <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="budgetQ2" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="Column9" HeaderText="Q3Bud" readonly="false" runat="server" DataField="Q3B" Width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                    <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="budgetQ3" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="Column10" HeaderText="Q4Bud" readonly="false" runat="server" DataField="Q4B" Width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                    <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="budgetQ4" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
                </cc1:Column>


                <cc1:Column ID="Column4" HeaderText="Q1App" readonly="true" runat="server" DataField="Q1A" Width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="Column5" HeaderText="Q2App" readonly="true" runat="server" DataField="Q2A" Width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="Column6" HeaderText="Q3App" readonly="true" runat="server" DataField="Q3A" Width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="Column7" HeaderText="Q4App" readonly="true" runat="server" DataField="Q4A" Width="100" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                </cc1:Column>

                 <cc1:Column ID="Column13" HeaderText="Year" readonly="true" Visible="false" runat="server" DataField="year" FooterStyle-Font-Size="Smaller" Width="60">
                     <FooterStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />

                </cc1:Column>
            </Columns>

                     <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateId="tplRowEdit" />

        <Templates>                
            <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tplRowEdit">
                <Template>
                    <table class="rowEditTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <fieldset style="width: 275px; height: 175px;">
                                    <legend>Budget Amount</legend>
                                    <table class="rowEditTable">                                                                
                                        <tr> 
                                        <br />
                                            <td>Quarter 1:</td>
                                            <td> <cc1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="budgetQ1" Width="150"></cc1:OboutTextBox>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Quarter 2:</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <cc1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="budgetQ2" Width="150"></cc1:OboutTextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Quarter 3:</td>
                                            <td>
                                               <cc1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="budgetQ3" Width="150"></cc1:OboutTextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Quarter 4:</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <cc1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="budgetQ4" Width="150"></cc1:OboutTextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>                                                               
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                <br />

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </fieldset>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                                <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="budgetGrid.save()"  />
                                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="budgetGrid.cancel()"  /> 
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>                                            
                </Template>
            </cc1:GridTemplate>
        </Templates>

        </cc1:Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution some time ago , i created the gridview in the page load event from zero and by doing so i got full control on all the changes editing etc, which seem to cause many problems while trying to do so with existing gridview on the html view.